# How do I fix the width of text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In the following code snippet:

```
<span style="width:250px">test</span><span>test2</span>
```

I want 'test' to occupy 250 pixels without changing the size of the text. In other words, I would like the word 'test' to print, followed by however may pixels is required to reach a total width of 250 pixels (test + blank space) then the word 'test2' to print afterwards. What CSS do I use to achieve this?

Comment: Span will only span the length of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c5zN2/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<span class="width250">test</span><span>test2</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.width250{        
    width:250px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: It can work without display: block if you are using float http://jsfiddle.net/c5zN2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add block display

```
<span style="width:250px; display:block;">test</span><span>test2</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use CSS like this.

```
<span style="width: 250px; display: inline-block;">test</span>
<span>test2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a new line use

```
display:inline-block
```

instead of block!